# Advice on how to predict future time series data

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series

Data: 
I have time series data for different countries and factors, e.g. birth rate for "Afghanistan" for years from 1972 up until 2007 ([source](https://www.drivendata.org/competitions/1/)).

Goal:
Predict e.g. birth rate for 2008 and 2012

Question: 
I am familiar with linear regressions, but need some help on how to work with time series data and predict future values.

Can you point me to examples or share code snippets?

Comment: Are you mostly interested in `python` implementations?

Comment: yes, I am, Stefan.

Comment: Then `statsmodels` (see below) is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `statsmodels` [Time Series Analysis](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/tsa.html) module. Time series models are often based around autocorrelation, and the module has the standard univariate (for individual time series) `AR(p)` and `MA(p)` models, as well as the combined version `ARIMA` that allows for `unit roots`. You'll also find multivariate (for various interrelated time series) `VAR` models.

And here's a `time series` [tutorial](http://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/time-series-forecasting-codes-python/) for statistical analysis and forecasting using `pandas` and `statsmodels`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ARIMA`  model and `VAR` Model in R.

`ARIMA`: Auto Regressive Integrated Moving Average model

`VAR`: Vector Auto Regressive model

For `ARIMA` model: [click here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/arima.html)

For `VAR` model: [click here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf)

For one time series data, use `ARIMA` model, however, if multiple time series data are related to each other, use `VAR` model.